# Positioning widgets on frames with Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, frame

So, I'm fairly new to Python, and Tkinter.
I'm in the process of creating a Battleship game. So far I've succesfully created a grid of buttons. I am now trying to create a sort of a menu to the right of this game pad. I'm trying to do this by having two different Frames in my window - one where my game pad is and one where I have the menu (which is below a Label).
Whatever I put inside cheat_button.grid() I can't seem to change the position of this button. It just stays in the top-left corner of the menu_frame Frame. I also want to add anothern button beneath this one, as well as a message box a bit further down, on the same frame. Any suggestions? I have linked the part of the code I find relevant.

Thanks.

```
col_tot = 10
row_tot = 10

self.grid_frame = tk.Frame(self)
self.grid_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=row_tot, columnspan=col_tot, sticky = "WENS")

self.menu_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="grey", bd=1, relief="ridge")
self.menu_frame.grid(row=1, column=col_tot, rowspan=row_tot-1, columnspan=4, sticky = "WENS")


button_no = 0


self.button_list = []   
for x in range(row_tot):            
  self.button_list.append([""] * col_tot)


for i in range(row_tot):

  for j in range(col_tot):

    self.button_list[i][j] = (tk.Button(self.grid_frame, height = 3, width = 6, text = str(button_no + 1),
      activebackground = "yellow", relief = "groove"))
    self.button_list[i][j]["command"] = lambda i=i, j=j:self.update_colour(i, j)
    self.button_list[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j, sticky = "NW")

    button_no += 1

self.welcome = tk.Label(self, text = "Welcome to Battleship!",
  fg = "red", bg = "grey", font = ("Helvetica", 12), relief="ridge")
self.welcome.grid(row = 0, column = col_tot, columnspan = 4, sticky = "WENS")


self.cheat_button = tk.Button(self.menu_frame, text = "Cheat")
self.cheat_button.grid()
self.cheat_button.config(bg = "grey")
```

Comment: That's normal since it is the only children of `menu_frame` so all other rows/columns have a height/width of 0.

Comment: @j_4321, OK, if that's the case, I'm not sure how to get around it... Suggestions on how to do this in a better way?

Comment: did you have a look at the place geometry manager? http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm

Comment: @ArcoBast Yes, however I'd like to do this with .grid(). It's the one I'm comfortable with.

Comment: Where do you want the button, if not at the top left?

Comment: @BryanOakley I want it more or less centered in the menu_frame, maybe a bit above center. I'd try to do this by setting (for example) row = 4 and column = 2. But it just wont move no matter what I set its row, column, rowspan and columnspan as...

Comment: @CalleFreme did you set the weights of the rows / columns to something positive? You can do this using this method: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method

Answer (score 1):

Rows and columns have a size of zero if they are empty and haven't configured to have a minimum size. It's also important to know that each frame has it's own "grid", so even though the frame on the left has 10 rows and ten columns, the frame on the right starts out completely empty.

If you want the button centered in the frame, one solution is to leave an empty row above and below it, and configure those rows to be given any extra space. For example:

```
self.welcome.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "WENS")
# notice we've put nothing in rows 1 or 3
self.cheat_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

self.menu_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
self.menu_frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This helped me part of the way! However, I still find this confusing. If I make my menu_frame Frame span 5 columns for example, does that not mean it contains 5 columns for me to place widgets in? And if I then do something like:
`
(for c in range(4):
   self.menu_frame.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1))
`
and the same thing for my rows in that Frame, shouldn't I be able to place widgets exactly where I want them? So far, it's not working quite like I expected... If I set column=3 for a button, shouldn't it end up in the middle of my columns of this frame?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I don't think that the empty rows above and below are necessary. Just doing `self.cheat_button.grid(row=0, column=0)` and `self.menu_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` is enough to center the button vertically.

Comment: @j_4321: you are correct, the empty rows aren't strictly necessary. I can think of half a dozen different ways to center the button. This, to me, was the simplest.

Comment: @CalleFreme: _"If I make my menu_frame Frame span 5 columns for example, does that not mean it contains 5 columns for me to place widgets in?"_ - no, that's not what it means. If you make the frame span five columns, it only means that it spans five columns in its parent. Inside of it, you still start out with a blank slate so to speak. The rows and columns inside the frame are completely independent of the rows and columns of the parent.